# MS Word grammar check showing "correction" identical to the original text, accepting correction then ruins formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011, grammar

If I examine the green squiggle and open the grammar dialog, it says there is an extra space between two words but I have positioned and moved the cursor and can confirm that this is not the case

If I accept the correction, it collapses the spacing between the letters of the second word so that the letters overlap

Why does it think there is an error?

Comment: I should add that this document was originally created in a Windows version of word. Also inserting the cursor immediately after the first word and before the space and retyping the word gets rid of the problem. But there are tons of instances and I don't want to have to manually retype them. Interestingly this seems to be occurring with the final two words on each sentence

Answer (score 0):

The *space* you see is potentially not a normal space, but a tab, a non-breakable space, or one of some other similar special-purpose characters (no-orphan-space?)

To see them, try switching visibility on for all characters (the button looks like an inverted P).

You can copy one of those 'funny' blanks (shift & cursor, ctrl+C) and, using find/replace, paste it into source (ctrl+V), and put a normal blank into the target; that should clean them up all at once.